# python3 package cannot be imported as non-root user

Tags: python, pip, python-3.6

I'm trying to import a python3 module using pip3 as root user. I could import the same installed python3 module as root user. Now when I try to import that module after exiting from sudo and as normal user, I cannot import it. I added the PYTHONPATH variable with installed module path. Still I could not figure out the issue.

Basically I need the installed python3 library to be used by any user who logs in to the machine.

```
[root@mymachine /home/user]
 pip3 install kubernetes
```

The command was successsful as you can see below:

```
[root@mymachine /home/user]
 python3 -c "import kubernetes"
```

Now I exited from root user and got logged in as "user" and tried to `import kubernetes` here. It failed.

```
[user@mymachine]
$ python3 -c "import kubernetes"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kubernetes'
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the commands you used to install the module, as well as the code where you import the module. Additionally, please add the **full text** of any errors or tracebacks.

Comment: So? Where is the installed module path? What's your PYTHONPATH? Is it accessible by all users? What's the path to Python3 executable? Etc.

Comment: It is installed in path : /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages @user202729

Comment: Done @MattDMo as above.

Comment: Are you sure that `root` and `user` are using the same version of Python, and the same executable? Run `which python3` under both logins.

Comment: No, they are not using the same executable. user is using: 
`$ which  python3
/usr/bin/python3`

root user is using :
`# which python3
/bin/python3`

@MattDMo

Comment: Then fix that, or install the package again for the other Python installation.

Comment: What do you mean by fix that. @tripleee. Do I need to delete the /usr/bin/python3 executable.

Comment: No, I mean make them both run the same Python version by modifying the `PATH` for one or the other. You absolutely should not muck with system-installed files in `/usr`.

Comment: Since root is using /bin/python3 executable. As `user` I used same executable /bin/python3 to import kubernetes module. Still it is throwing no module error.

Answer (score 0):

as `user` run:

```
python3 -m pip install kubernetes
```

and then try running your code again

Comment: I'm trying to install a python3 module and use it for user whoever logs in. Like the module should be install global. Thanks for the tip though

Comment: unless each user uses a separate python environment, this should do the trick. If they all use different python environments, they all need to install Kubernetes in their own environment

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a file permission issue. try uninstall the package, make sure `umask` is `022` and reinstall it with `root` user or via `sudo` again. something like:

```
sudo pip uninstall kubernetes
umask 022
sudo pip install kubernetes
```